# Swift: use string variable in other file

Tags: swift, file, variables

I wrote an app in Swift where I have a page I can set settings for my game. After pressing the button for the settings, the file with the game opens. But how can I get the variable I want to set to my game file?

I tried to work around this by creating a struct in the first file where I set a variable that I can change by pressing the button and which I later call on my game page. But it didn't work (the variable needed to be static, so I couldn't change it). Also it didn't seem like a smart way for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
struct Globals {

    static var score: Int = 0

    // Any other global variables you want.
}
```

Access by:

```
let score = Globals.score
```

You can also store information in `UserDefaults` to persist across launches of the app.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually this was exactly what I wrote, but I wasn't able to change the static variable, when I pressed the button.

Comment: Was my bad, I miss interpreted an error. Your way worked. Thank you so much!